# Balance not getting updated in my Java program

Tags: java

I wrote a java program in which the subclass is `BankAccount` and `SavingsAccount` is the subclass of it, and I am doing some transactions with it but the balance is not getting updated and only shows 0.00 as the output.

Here is my code:

```java
public class BankAccountTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SavingsAccount savingsAccount = new SavingsAccount(879101,0,0.04);
        savingsAccount.deposit(500);
        savingsAccount.withdraw(500);
        savingsAccount.deposit(1500);
        savingsAccount.deposit(500);
        savingsAccount.withdraw(500);
        savingsAccount.deposit(5000);
        savingsAccount.deposit(500);
        savingsAccount.annualCredit();
        System.out.println(savingsAccount);

    }
}
```

```java
class BankAccount {

        private int accountNumber;
        protected double balance;



    public BankAccount( int accountNumber, double balance)
        {
            this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
            this.balance = balance;
        }

        public int getAccountNumber () {
            return accountNumber;
        }

        public double getBalance () {
            return balance;
        }

        public void setAccountNumber ( int accountNumber){
            this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        }

        public void setBalance ( double balance){
            this.balance = balance;
        }

        public void deposit ( double amount){
            balance = balance + amount;
        }

        public void withdraw ( double amount){
            if (amount <= balance)
                balance = balance - amount;
        }


        public String toString () {
            return String.format("Account Number=%d%nBalance=%.2f%n", accountNumber, balance);
        }

    }
```

```java
class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount{

    private double interestRate;

    public SavingsAccount(int accountNumber, double balance, double interestRate) {
        super(accountNumber, balance);
    }
    public void deposit(double amount){
        balance = balance+(interestRate*amount);

    }
    public void withdraw(double amount) {
        super.withdraw(amount);
    }


    public void annualCredit(){
        if (balance<=1000){
            balance=interestRate*balance;
        }
        else if(balance<=5000){
            balance=2*interestRate*balance;
        }
        else if(balance>5000){
            balance=3*interestRate*balance;
        }
    }
    public double getInterestRate(){
        return interestRate;
    }



    public String toString(){
        System.out.println("Account= "+getAccountNumber()+"\nBalance= "+balance+"\nInterestRate= "+interestRate);
        return null;
    }

}
```

And the output:

```
Account= 879101
Balance= 0.0
InterestRate= 0.0
null
```

Comment: InterestRate is 0, you multiply balance by it in annualCredit

Comment: Not sure if it is your intention or if it got cut-out during copy-pasting but declaring classes in java without an access modifier (e.g. `public`) means they default to being `package-private`. See here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never set `interestRate` in your `SavingsAccount` constructor. Since deposits are multiplied by that (and it's zero) it never updates.

```
public SavingsAccount(int accountNumber, double balance, double interestRate) {
    super(accountNumber, balance);
    this.interestRate = interestRate;
}
```

Also, interest should probably not be paid on deposit.

```
public void deposit(double amount) {
    balance += amount;
}
```

Comment: That fixed my balance updating part but the output is still not coming as expected because of some problem in checkingsAccount for which the middle else if statement should be greater than 1000 but less than 5000, which i dont know how to do.

Comment: @Ibrahim That sounds like a new question; I don't see `checkingsAccount` (at all) in your post.

Comment: Sorry, i meant Savingsaccount itself,

Comment: The question states that when user deposits money, he is credited amount equal to interestRate multiplied by the deposit amount.  and annual credit is if balance is less than 1000, balance will be multiplied by interest rate. If less or equal to 5000 then 2*interestRate and greater than 5000 is 3*interestRate.

Comment: Your "middle else if" does exactly what you said in your comment. You really need to tell us everything in the question.

Comment: The given output should be: Account=879101
Balance=$8198.4
InterestRate=0.04